# servletContext.getResourceAsStream(this.path) returns null on a modular application

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using `Spring boot 2.2` and `primefaces 6.2` in a modular application.so added a new module to send mail using templates with `thymeleaf-spring5`.
My send mail module It works very well as a monothelic application but i have this exception after the integration on my origin project,

My config :

```
@Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver(){
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        emailTemplateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        emailTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        emailTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        emailTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        return emailTemplateResolver;
    }
```

This is the exception when i try to send mail :

```
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/templates/admin-email-blocked-user.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:235)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:649)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1059)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1048)
    at fr.pasteur.flexlims.jms.Receiver.receiveMessage(Receiver.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/templates/admin-email-blocked-user.html]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:159)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresource.SpringResourceTemplateResource.reader(SpringResourceTemplateResource.java:103)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:223)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Nothing PrimeFaces related in here (not even in the stacktrace, not even JSF in the stacktrace.)

Comment: Nor [tag:javamail] either. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i don't know why but i should put my `templates` folder under `/resources/META-INF/resources` to work !